# In emacs23 how to bound C-<return> to C-<return> instead of C-J

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs23

I am trying to use org-mode and whenever I press Crtl+return emacs does C-J instead. I know this because when I use c-h k and then press crtl+return, emacs shows:
"It is bound to C-j." 
Is there anyway I can make it register ctrl+return so I can insert headings?

I am using emacs23 through the terminal on ubuntu 12.04 x64. When I do this on my windows machine it does insert a new heading.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/18000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly. As @phils says, <kbd>C-Enter</kbd> is usually not a valid sequence for the vast majority of terminal emulators. This is because when you press a key, or key combination, the terminal sends a sequence of characters to the relevant application. Pressing <kbd>a</kbd> sends `a`, whereas <kbd>Enter</kbd> sends `CR` - carriage return (otherwise known as `^M`, `\r` or `\015`).

What sequences are actually implemented in modern terminals is mostly just a hang-over from the earlier, physical, terminals that they emulate (notably the VT-100). These machines didn't allow the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in conjunction with every key, such as the function keys, for example, so <kbd>C-F1</kbd> was not possible and didn't have an escape sequence defined. Similarly, there is no control sequence for <kbd>C-Enter</kbd>, so when you press it, the terminal ignores the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and just sees the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You may, however, be able to define your own escape sequences in your terminal, which you can then bind to the correct key combinations in emacs. [See here, for example.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79561/40390) I was able to use this method to be able to use <kbd>C-Enter</kbd>. Unfortunately, this is still a bit of a pain, as it requires a lot of configuration and you may still be unable to use some sequences (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> doesn't work in konsole for me). As with @phils, I've taken to using the GUI, but I'd love to have better integration with my terminal.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid sequence for most terminals, I'm afraid, so they simply can't send it to Emacs.

If you run GUI Emacs instead, the key bindings will work.

[Thomas Dickey's xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) is the only terminal software I know of which can (I think) support all the normal Emacs bindings. If you're okay with compiling that, then you could try it with the following `.Xdefaults-(hostname)` (or `.Xresources` if you re-merge after editing) to get basic support working:

```
XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
XTerm*modifier: meta
XTerm*modifyOtherKeys: 1
```

You actually need `XTerm*modifyOtherKeys: 2` to fully extend the sequences (otherwise you still can't type the likes of `C-M-%`), but by default that setting will break most key sequences, and right now I couldn't tell you how to configure things correctly for that setting (the only example I've seen -- xterm-extras.el as mentioned on the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XtermExtras) and available in the [easymacs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymacs/) download -- didn't work for me).

I mostly use GUI Emacs, but I'd love to get this working properly, so if anyone has had success with xterm-extras.el or similar, please do speak up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install an Emacs package and configure your terminal, I wrote an Emacs package which can teach Emacs and terminals how to properly recognize all PC keyboard keys and modifier key combinations:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-keys

Its default configuration enables encoding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> combination, which allows Emacs to distinguish it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.