# ESS R code passing doesn't work in Emacs console mode

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I'm using Fedora 21 with GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and ESS version 15.03. In GUI mode I can use C-RET to pass code from an R script I'm editing to an inferior R process (it starts one up if I haven't yet), but that doesn't seem to work in console mode. Now C-RET just creates a new line in my R script. I've tried this using both `emacs` and `emacs-nox` installations.

I compiled ESS from source instead of using the outdated version in Fedora's package manager. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: What does `C-h k C-RET` say? It should be bound to `ess-eval-region-or-line-and-step`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize that I'm pressing `C-RET` instead of `RET`, which is simply bound to the `newline` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `C-RET` isn't a valid sequence in the terminal, so the `C-` is getting ignored and it's just interpreting the `RET`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275610/2921990) for more explanation. Following some of the links there will take you to some workarounds, but they are not ideal. It doesn't look like there are any ways to completely change this behavior in the terminal (but I'd love to be told I'm wrong).